# Load balancing for spring boot scheduler service

Tags: java, spring-boot, load-balancing

I created a java spring boot scheduler service using @Enablescheduler and @scheduler(cron=)  and need to run this on cluster.
Can some one help how can I create cluster load balancing the application.

Comment: It is not about loadbalancing but running the same task on different instances. Take a look what can offer Shedlock or Quartz. Then implement it for your purpose.

Answer (score 0):

You would actually need to make sure that once scheduled task has started on one node,
other nodes in the cluster are blocked to execute the same task.

You can use Shedlock for this purpose. You would need to create database table called **shedlock**,
and it should contain attributes: name, lock_at, lock_until, locked_by(node).

Then create a scheduled task like this:

```
@Scheduled(chron="..")
@SchedulerLock(name="..", lockAtLeast="..")
public void scheduledTask() {
    LockAssert.assertLocked();
    //do something
}
```

For more documentation try [Shedlock](https://github.com/lukas-krecan/ShedLock)